# I am getting the exit code 1 and could not found username for fetching the submodule in git hub action

Tags: python, git, action, hub

Failed to clone the submodule and the logs is showing as below

```
  Error: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

 The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 1
```

I have tried as below

name: clone submodule uses: actions/checkout@v2 with: submodules: recursive - name: Configure Git for Private Submodule run: | git config --global url."[github.com/".insteadOf](https://github.com/%22.insteadOf) "[ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com](https://ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com/)" git config --global credential.helper store git config --global user.email "my mail id" git config --global user.name "myusername" env: ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}